# Looking for the name of a curve from translating uniform circular motion

Tags: circles, curves

If you take uniform circular motion in the x,y plane and translate it along the z-axis you get a helix (attached pic courtesy of Wikipedia).  What is the name of the curve if I translate along the x, or y-axis? Thanks.

[image: Helix]

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/science/cycloid

Comment: Did that help??

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay. It seems that with the cycloid the translation velocity of the circle in the plane of rotation (say x direction) is coupled with the uniform circular velocity but I wanted them to be independent.  I'm going to see if I can figure it out from the equations but at least now I have a search term which is helpful for use. Thanks.